# Show how many items are hidden by CSS Overflow using jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow

Ive been digging all day on a way to handle this. Im showing color swatches for products but I want to only show 1 row and have the rest that don't fit within the box to be hidden and show either a + sign or +3,+4,+5 based on how many cant be seen. The box also changes sizes based on screen size.

[image: Color swatch example]

I'm open to ideas that dont use CSS overflow but I'm not sure where to start.

HTML and CSS is just one DIV with 15 image tags in it. Height of 20px and overflow:hidden. All of this doesnt matter as I can change it to anything needed though.

Comment: Can you include HTML and CSS at Question?

Comment: Why do not you use a carrousel or slider?

Comment: @guest271314 Its just one DIV with 15 image tags inside it. but I can change it if needed.

Comment: @LuisFernando Actually not a bad idea, but Id prefer a solution less heavy. I may do that for now! Id have dozens of sliders on one page.

Comment: For me it would be a good idea, I've seen the same thing on another website and it's a slider that never fails to show the colors.    
Can you include HTML and CSS at Question?